# Python SQLite3, how to add data to the database from the input fields?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I need to add data from the input fields and combobox, but when passing their values ​​through `get ()` the queries themselves are added (self.entry_description.get (), self.combobox.get ()) `. How to fix it?

```
    self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
    self.entry_description.place(x=200,y=50)
    self.entry_money = ttk.Entry(self)
    self.entry_money.place(x=200,y=110)

    self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=(u'Доходы',u'Расходы'),state='readonly')
    self.combobox.current(0)
    self.combobox.place(x=200,y=80)

    btn_add = tk.Button(self, text='Добавить', command = BD().add_item())
    btn_add.place(x=220, y=170)
    btn_add.bind('<Button-1>')

    btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Отменить', command=lambda: self.destroy())
    btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=170)
    btn_cancel.bind('<Button-1>')


    self.grab_set()
    self.focus_set()



class BD:
def create(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS albums (ID integer primary key,
                                                          description text,
                                                          costs text,
                                                          total real)""")
    conn.commit()

def add_item(self):
    cursor = sqlite3.connect('finance.db').cursor()
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO albums(description, costs, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""",
                  (self.entry_description.get(), self.combobox.get(), self.entry_money.get()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is currently happening is that you are passing string literals into the insert, which happen to be variable names.  You should use a prepared statement and then bind your Python variables:

```
cursor = sqlite3.connect('finance.db').cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO albums(description, costs, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""",
    (self.entry_description.get(), self.combobox.get(), self.entry_money.get()))
```

Comment: self.entry_description place on other class, and when i run my app i get an AttributeError, can we halp me with this?

Comment: I can't help, because I don't know anything about the rest of your code or data.  The general pattern I gave _should_ work, assuming you are binding legitimate values.